# How to convert date with c# windows form app?

Tags: c#

II want to make a date converter app with c# windows form app.I had use following code but I could use it just for that date.

```
System.Globalization.PersianCalendar pc;
pc = new System.Globalization.PersianCalendar();
year_label1.Text = pc.GetYear(DateTime.Now).ToString();
```

I want to give a date an the convert Persian calendar to Julian Calendar.I want use this app to sort my camera pic's name (that is in Persian calendar name) to folders in Julian calendar names.
Thanks!

Comment: It is rather unclear what you are attempting to do - can you explain in detail, with a few examples?

Comment: What is wrong with your current code? It works only with the year? Then use one of the other Get functions! See also [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/82aak18x.aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

However it seems you actually know the answer, but anyway you can convert Persian to Julian date like this:

```
public static DateTime PersianDateToJulianDate(DateTime persianDate)
{
    PersianCalendar pc = new PersianCalendar();

    return new DateTime(persianDate.Year, persianDate.Month, persianDate.Day, pc);
}

public static DateTime JulianDateToPersianDate(DateTime persianDate)
{
    PersianCalendar pc = new PersianCalendar();

    return new DateTime(pc.GetYear(persianDate),
                         pc.GetMonth(persianDate),
                         pc.GetDayOfMonth(persianDate));
}
```

Then you can call these functions like this:

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Parse("1392/01/11");
DateTime julian = PersianDateToJulianDate(now);     //convert to julian
DateTime persian = JulianDateToPersianDate(julian); //convert back again
```